# Populate c# list with results from table from stored procedure that returns multiple tables

Tags: c#, sql, list

I have a stored procedure that return 3 tables .  All I care about populating the `List` with is the result set from the last table the stored procedure returns; which has 3 columns. I have the following code so far:

```
string connStr = null;
SqlConnection scnn;
SqlCommand sCmd;
string sql = null;

connStr = "Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=dbName;Integrated Security=SSPI";
sql = @"DECLARE @udt1 userDefTblType1;" +
       "INSERT INTO @one (uid) VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3);" +
       "DECLARE @udt2 userDefTblType2;" +
       "INSERT INTO @two (uid) VALUES (0);" +
       "DECLARE @udt3 userDefTblType3;" +
       "INSERT INTO @three (uid) VALUES (0),(1);" +
       "EXEC [dbo].[storedProcedure] @one, @two, @three;";

sqlCnn = new SqlConnection(connStr);

try
{
    sCnn.Open();
    sCmd = new SqlCommand(sql, sCnn);
    SqlDataReader sReader = sCmd.ExecuteReader();

    sReader.Read();
    sReader.NextResult(); //move to next table

    sReader.Read();
    sReader.NextResult(); //move to next table

    sReader.Read();  //table of interest
    List<decimal> results = new List<decimal>();
    while (sReader.Read())
    {
        results.Items.Add(sqlReader["column1"].ToString());  //my problem is here
        results.Items.Add(sqlReader["column2"].ToString());  //my problem is here
        results.Items.Add(sqlReader["column2"].ToString());  //my problem is here                
    };

    sqlReader.Close();
    sqlCmd.Dispose();
    sqlCnn.Close();
}

catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Can not open connection ! ");
}
```

I need to fill the list like column1, column2, column3 respectively for as many rows there are so that I can populate an HTML table.

May you advise on what I am doing wrong; am I taking the right approach?

Thanks (I am starting to get a little more advance in C#, I do more db dev)

**EDIT:**

The following is an example of the 3rd table the stored proc returns:

```
Column1 | Column2 | Column3
---------------------------
5.6     | 5.1     | 7.4    |
5.7     | 5.4     | 7.7    |
5.8     | 5.6     | 7.9    |
5.9     | 5.8     | 7.0    |
5.1     | 5.6     | 7.7    |
```

I have code already dynamically written for a html table.  I just need to store these results some where to enumerate through them so can add the values to the relative html tabs in my code.

**EDIT:**

In the end I want my code to look something like this:

```
html.WriteLine("<tr>");
while (colCount <= numCol)
{
html.WriteLine("<td>" POSITION IN <LIST> + "</td>");
cFinalColCount++;
}
html.WriteLine("</tr>");
rowCount++;
```

Comment: *Please* put more effort into formatting your code when you ask a question. By now you should have the hang of using the editor - don't make other people do the work of making your question readable.

Comment: My apologies to the community

Comment: Next, your question is really unclear - you have a `List<decimal>`... how do you expect that to have three values per row? Do you mean you want the total size of the list to be 3 * row count? It's also not clear why you're calling `ToString` or trying to add them to `resultSet` (which we haven't seen) if you're trying to populate a list...

Comment: I haven't  used lists before, should I have created 3 lists (1 for each column)?

Comment: @AdamV that was a typo....will make edit

Comment: @JeffOrris: Maybe. Or - probably better - a list of a new class with three decimal properties in it. It's hard to tell.

Comment: @JeffOrris - that depends on what you're doing with them. Your question has sufficiently removed enough context that we don't know what your intent is.

Comment: @AdamV I am populating an HTML table with the results of the table,  I have the code set up already to populate...I just need to enumerate through a List (or something else if need be) so that I can populate the HTML table

Comment: Ill add example table

Comment: Also, you're pulling them out as strings and adding them to a collection of decimals.

Comment: Again, haven't ever used a list before.  The results from the table are decimal values which is why I did that.

Comment: @AdamV no...I don't need help writing the HTML...I already wrote that logic....the code block I added is just a small little piece (just showing why I want to run through list of table results)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a gridview for tabling data in your html. It's much easier than building your own tables.

C# code:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
try
{
    sCnn.Open();
    sCmd = new SqlCommand(sql, sCnn);
    SqlDataReader sReader = sCmd.ExecuteReader();

    sReader.Read();
    sReader.NextResult(); //move to next table

    sReader.Read();
    sReader.NextResult(); //move to next table

    dt.Load(sReader); // Convert your data reader to a DataTable

    sqlReader.Close();
    sqlCmd.Dispose();
    sqlCnn.Close();


    // UNTESTED CODE - but it should be close. 

    GridView gv = new GridView(); // create gridview
    gv.DataSource = dt; // Set the DataTable as the DataSource for the GridView
    gv.DataBind(); // Bind the Data to the GridView
    StringWriter sWriter = new StringWriter(); //stringwriter needed for html writer
    HtmlTextWriter htWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(sWriter); // create HthmWriter
    gv.RenderControl(htWriter); //render the gridview in the htmlwriter
    htWriter.Write(true); // write the html writer to the output stream

}

catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Can not open connection ! ");
}
```

Comment: I'm building a Class (not in ASP.NET), that another programmer is going to call my method generateTable() ...he is using js ....can I still use this method?  this type of programming is new to me.--p.s. I like your approach.

Comment: I edited the code above so that it can be used by an ajax call. It is untested code. However, if it doesn't work it should be close. I will say that normally when I do ajax calls, I just want the data in a json format then I can sort, select and use the data as needed in the javascript. But If you're just injecting the html into a div this should work.

Answer (score 0):

[As JonSkeet suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32977282/populate-c-sharp-list-with-results-from-table-from-stored-procedure-that-returns#comment53780004_32977282), what makes the most sense is to declare a class with three decimals as properties (preferably with sensible names, such as below):

```
public class Volume
{
  public decimal Length { get; set; }
  public decimal Width { get; set; }
  public decimal Height { get; set; }
}
```

Then you'll create a `List` of `Volume` objects:

```
List<Volume> results = new List<Volume>();
while (sReader.Read())
{
  // Error checking elided
  var length = decimal.Parse(sqlReader["column1"]);
  var width = decimal.Parse(sqlReader["column2"]);
  var height = decimal.Parse(sqlReader["column3"]);
  results.Add(new Volume { Length = length, Width = width, Height = height });
};
```

Comment: Note: I picked `Volume` at random. I just wanted something where three decimal values made sense.